# Android App to App Communication

Tags: android, ios, iphone, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I am android beginner. Please, give me suggestion that which procedure do I will follow to develop the app like:

**For example:** How I can communicate between App to App? 
**Like for example** I want to sent an image or any other data to the another device or App, Kindly help me out with this.

Thank You

```
switch (intent.getIntExtra(Constants.EXTENDED_DATA_STATUS,
                Constants.STATE_ACTION_COMPLETE)) {
```

**OR**

Is there any possibility app to app communication without using push notification?
I want to send an image from one app to another,some suggestion and advice will be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: anyone experience software developer suggest me somthing..

Comment: but through bluetooth the device to device communication not app to app communication,it is not?and i want app to app communication.

Comment: You may use a webservice as a intermediator since in android peer2peer communication is not supported or u could use WIFI p2p as suggested by @Moubeen Farooq

Comment: and sorry i forget to mention,i am using gprs,not wifi etc

Comment: so you could use some web services of your own.

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m so u mean through push notification i am achieving this?

Comment: No use a webservice through which your apps can connect

Comment: yes,,there is no webservice through which my apps connect..

Answer (score 1):

To Share The Data Between the Devices One of the way is Wi-Fi Direct For that here is the link for the demo [source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java_Free_Code/Image/Download_wifi_direct_demo_Free_Java_Code.htm) and the documentation is on [This](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) link. Hope It Will Help.

Comment: Moubeen Farooq Khan thanks for ur reply kindly can u tell me that Is there any possibility app to app communication without using push notification?
I want to send an image from one app to another,some suggestion and advice will be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Through push Notification you can send the url of the image.....and it can be accessed on the other mobile phone if the image exists on the web....... if this is the easiest way ..... without push notification you can send image through Bluetooth and wifi.....

Comment: but through bluetooth and wifi this is the device to device communication not app to app communication,it is not?

Answer (score 0):

The communication between apps on a device is very different from communication between devices.

Within a device, you communicate between apps using Intents.

```
// send text
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);

// send binary data
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

If you want to share between devices on a network, then using some sort of TCP/IP or UDP protocol may work, but generally I find that Bluetooth is the easiest solution.  Both applications need to be aware of the communication, but it's straightforward enough.

There is a good article here:  http://java.dzone.com/articles/bluetooth-data-transfer

Essentially, the gist's that you:

1. Find the other device
2. Pair with the other device
3. Send the file

The sample code looks like this:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
// duration that the device is discoverable
private static final int DISCOVER_DURATION = 300;

// our request code (must be greater than zero)
private static final int REQUEST_BLU = 1;
//...
public void enableBlu(){
// enable device discovery - this will automatically enable Bluetooth
Intent discoveryIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);

discoveryIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,
                            DISCOVER_DURATION );

startActivityForResult(discoveryIntent, REQUEST_BLU);
}
```

Then to receive:

```
// When startActivityForResult completes...
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode,
                                 Intent data) {

  if (resultCode == DISCOVER_DURATION
       && requestCode == REQUEST_BLU) {
      // processing code goes here
  }
  else{ // cancelled or error
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.blu_cancelled,
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

You can use your own Bluetooth intent instead of the OS one too, if you need to do so.  You can get the source for the Bluetooth intent from the AOSP code.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply kindely Is there any possibility app to app communication without using push notification? I want to send an image from one app to another,some suggestion and advice will be much appreciated.The requirement is app to app communication,any suggesstion and help will be much appreciated..